# самба во время проверки входа

Tags: сервер, samba, контроллер-домена

появилась проблема,
при попытке проверить работу самбы получаю

```
root@callserver:~# smbclient -L localhost -U%
session setup failed: NT_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR
```

при уровне дебага 3 вижу

```
root@callserver:~# smbclient -d 3 -L localhost -U%
lp_load_ex: refreshing parameters
Initialising global parameters
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
Processing section "[global]"
WARNING: The "syslog only" option is deprecated
added interface enp0s31f6:VoIP ip=192.168.0.1 bcast=192.168.0.255 netmask=255.255.255.0
added interface enp3s0 ip=192.168.1.250 bcast=192.168.1.255 netmask=255.255.255.0
added interface enp0s31f6 ip=192.168.10.1 bcast=192.168.10.255 netmask=255.255.255.0
added interface enp4s0 ip=10.0.0.2 bcast=10.0.0.255 netmask=255.255.255.0
Client started (version 4.6.7-Ubuntu).
resolve_lmhosts: Attempting lmhosts lookup for name localhost<0x20>
resolve_wins: WINS server resolution selected and no WINS servers listed.
resolve_hosts: Attempting host lookup for name localhost<0x20>
Connecting to 127.0.0.1 at port 445
got OID=1.2.840.48018.1.2.2
GENSEC backend 'gssapi_spnego' registered
GENSEC backend 'gssapi_krb5' registered
GENSEC backend 'gssapi_krb5_sasl' registered
GENSEC backend 'spnego' registered
GENSEC backend 'schannel' registered
GENSEC backend 'naclrpc_as_system' registered
GENSEC backend 'sasl-EXTERNAL' registered
GENSEC backend 'ntlmssp' registered
GENSEC backend 'ntlmssp_resume_ccache' registered
GENSEC backend 'http_basic' registered
GENSEC backend 'http_ntlm' registered
GENSEC backend 'krb5' registered
GENSEC backend 'fake_gssapi_krb5' registered
Got challenge flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x62898215
NTLMSSP: Set final flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x62008a15
NTLMSSP Sign/Seal - Initialising with flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x62008a15
SPNEGO login failed: An internal error occurred.
session setup failed: NT_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR
```

чем это лечится? не могу провести проверку на этапе проверок. главное что 
остальные проверки и симлинк проходит без нареканий
kinit

```
root@callserver:~# kinit administrator@SRVR1.LAN
Password for administrator@SRVR1.LAN:
Warning: Your password will expire in 41 days on Wed Nov 28 11:06:54 2018

root@callserver:~# host -t SRV _ldap._tcp.srvr1.lan.
_ldap._tcp.srvr1.lan has SRV record 0 100 389 callserver.srvr1.lan.
root@callserver:~# host -t SRV _kerberos._udp.srvr1.lan
_kerberos._udp.srvr1.lan has SRV record 0 100 88 callserver.srvr1.lan.
root@callserver:~# host -t A callserver.srvr1.lan
callserver.srvr1.lan has address 192.168.1.250
callserver.srvr1.lan has address 192.168.10.1
callserver.srvr1.lan has address 10.0.0.2
callserver.srvr1.lan has address 192.168.0.1
```

Comment: я уже спрашивал на форуме ubuntu samba, но там никто так внятно и не может помочь. вот ссылка на остальные данные [форум](https://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=242325.msg2361030#msg2361030)

Answer (score 1):

проблема решилась простой перезагрузкой

Comment: По-моему, это нормальный ответ. Есть проблема - есть решение. Не расписывать же в ответе как проводилась перезагрузка сервера...